# How to display total number from start to a range in php

Tags: php

How to display total number from start to end in a range in php .Each time number will increase by 10 .

For example total number is 35

Then number will display this way :

```
         1  to 10
         11 to 20
         21 to 30
         31 to 35
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop that increments by `10`, and an `if` statement that checks that you are not going above `35`. This is not difficult, you should be able to figure it by simply giving it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$num=35;
for($i=1;$i<$num;$i=$i+10)
{
$j=$i+9;
if($j>$num)
   $j=$num;
echo $i.' to '. $j;
}
```

Comment: here last value is: 31 to 40 , but I need 31 to 35

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$num=35;
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++) {
  if($i %10 == 0)
    echo $i.'<br>';
  else
    echo $i;
}
```

will output :-

```
12345678910
11121314151617181920
21222324252627282930
3132333435
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop like this

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 35, $x += 10){
  echo $x . " to " . $x+9;
}
```

This will work i hope.

Thanks